# What is the meaning of component err.rate of class randomForest?

Tags: classification, random-forest, bootstrap, bagging

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539505/what-is-the-meaning-of-component-err-rate-of-class-randomforest) on Stackoverflow, but it's likely that I will received no answer on that site. So I cross-post my question here.

---

I'm using the function `randomForest` from package `randomForest`. One of the objects of class randomForest is `err.rate` which is

> (classification only) vector error rates of the prediction on the input data, the i-th element being the (OOB) error rate for all trees up to the i-th.

Could you please explain what is the meaning of this component? Thank you so much for your help!

I take the dataset `Sonar, Mines vs. Rocks` as an code example.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
library(boot)
library(randomForest)

n <- 208
ntrain <- 100
ntest <- 108
train.idx <- sample(1:n, ntrain, replace = FALSE)
train.set <- Sonar[train.idx, ]
test.set <- Sonar[-train.idx, ]

rf <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = train.set, keep.inbag = TRUE, importance = TRUE)
head(rf$err.rate)
```

Here is the result of the code

```
             OOB         M         R
  [1,] 0.1891892 0.1500000 0.2352941
  [2,] 0.2931034 0.2307692 0.3437500
  [3,] 0.2739726 0.2647059 0.2820513
  [4,] 0.2911392 0.2894737 0.2926829
  [5,] 0.2413793 0.2682927 0.2173913
  [6,] 0.2555556 0.2142857 0.2916667
  [7,] 0.2553191 0.2444444 0.2653061
  [8,] 0.2268041 0.1956522 0.2549020
  [9,] 0.2783505 0.2608696 0.2941176
```

Comment: The OOB error rate is the "out-of-bag" error rate, i.e., the error rate when predicting the observations not selected for training.   The $i$th element is the OOB error rate for predictions based on the first $i$ trees; this is useful because as you train more trees, you expect the OOB error rate to decrease, but more-or-less stabilize (decrease very slowly) after a while, and it's useful to know when.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated support @jbowman ;)

Comment: That's what we're here for!